# Query that populates a datasheet in MS Access, and MsgBox if no values returned

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a query that can run from a button in MS Access.  The SQL query I've created is below:

```
PARAMETERS CASNUMBER Text ( 255 ); 
SELECT DISTINCT Chemical.Chemical_Name, Hazard.Hazard_Code, Hazard.Hazard_Text 
FROM Chemical, Chemical_Hazard, Hazard 
WHERE Chemical.Chemical_Id = Chemical_Hazard.Chemical_Id 
and Chemical_Hazard.Hazard_Id = Hazard.Hazard_Id 
and [CASNUMBER] = Chemical.CAS
```

;

How do I make it so that a MsgBox appears when there are no values returned?

Comment: What does your button do now? Do you have the VBA code that Opens the querydef recordset, passing the CASNUMBER from the user? After that you just check for your ecordset.EOF - if true - no records returned - open a MsgBox

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend join tables using `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`. Also you can avoid using parameter, which in most cases requres VBA code for query execution. Just create query without parameter, add CAS to columns list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Chemical.Chemical_Name
    ,Hazard.Hazard_Code
    ,Hazard.Hazard_Text
    ,Chemical.CAS
FROM (
    Chemical_Hazard INNER JOIN Chemical ON Chemical.Chemical_Id = Chemical_Hazard.Chemical_Id
    )
INNER JOIN Hazard ON Chemical_Hazard.Hazard_Id = Hazard.Hazard_Id
```

And then check for CAS in code:

```
If DCount("*", "MyQuery", "CAS=" & lngCASNumber) = 0 then
    MsgBox "CAS not found"
End If
```

Comment: User input goes to variable `lngCASNumber` in my example, textbox field can be used instead of variable. I removed last condition because it moved to Dcount function where clause: `"CAS=" & lngCASNumber`